# Scrapy. How to resolve 520?

Tags: scrapy

This website response

```
DEBUG: Crawled (520) <GET https://ddlfr.pw/> (referer: None)
```

How can i resolve this ?

I post my code for explain

import json

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request, Selector

class LoginSpider(Spider):
    name = 'ddlfr.pw'
    start_urls = ['https://ddlfr.pw/index.php?do=search']
    numero = 0
    def parse(self, response):
        global numero
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            headers = {'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'},
            formdata= {'dosearch': 'Rechercher', 'story': 'musso', 'do': 'search' , 'subaction': 'search', 'search_start': str(self.numero) , 'full_search': '0', 'result_form': '1'},
            callback=self.after_login,
            dont_filter = True
        )

    def after_login(self, response):
        for title in response.xpath('//div[@class="short nl nl2"]'):
            yield {'roman': title.extract()}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes because the web require valid browser's headers. while scrapy send headers as a bot.

Try to use these headers:

```
headers = {
        'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'
    }
```

[image: forget example, verify headers and output]

You can see crawled status over your website

Comment: it is working on my end, try using user-agent's mesh.

Comment: i test your sample and it's 200 but why with FormRequest i have 520? can u test with formRequest pls ?


return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            headers = {'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'},
            formdata= {'dosearch': 'Rechercher', 'story': 'musso', 'do': 'search' , 'subaction': 'search', 'search_start': '0' , 'full_search': '0', 'result_form': '1'},
            callback=self.after_login,
            dont_filter = True
        )

Comment: I have answered your question. Please ask your another , in other question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you monitor what your web browser does when you send the form from the web browser (Network tab of the developer tools), and try to reproduce the request with Scrapy.

In Firefox, for example, you can copy the successful request from the Network tab as a `curl` command, which is a clear representation of the request.