# How to overcome Scrapy - DEBUG: Crawled (520) problem?

Tags: python, scrapy, html-parsing

I've just wrote Scrapy spider from [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583365/response-works-in-scrapy-shell-but-doesnt-work-in-code) question (also mentioned in [THIS](https://github.com/iStoriesMedia/Scrapy_tutorials/blob/main/bestsellers/bestsellers/spiders/book_spider.py) repo). Seems like it worked a year ago but now book24.ru blocks spiders and returns 520 error.

Shell response with 520 error:

```
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.7.1 started (bot: bestsellers)
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.9.2.0, libxml2 2.9.14, cssselect 1.2.0, parsel 1.7.0, w3lib 2.1.1, Twisted 22.10.0, Python 3.10.6 (main, Nov 14 2022, 16:10:14) [GCC 11.3.0], pyOpenSSL 23.0.0 (OpenSSL 3.0.7 1 Nov 2022), cryptography 39.0.0, Platform Linux-5.15.0-58-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings:
{'BOT_NAME': 'bestsellers',
 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'bestsellers.spiders',
 'REQUEST_FINGERPRINTER_IMPLEMENTATION': '2.7',
 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['bestsellers.spiders'],
 'TWISTED_REACTOR': 'twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor'}
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [asyncio] DEBUG: Using selector: EpollSelector
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using reactor: twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.utils.log] DEBUG: Using asyncio event loop: asyncio.unix_events._UnixSelectorEventLoop
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet Password: cb384b87b1e215df
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to acquire lock 140382385887728 on /home/user/.cache/python-tldextract/3.10.6.final__first_scrapy-rekTiTXv__400173__tldextract-3.4.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 140382385887728 acquired on /home/user/.cache/python-tldextract/3.10.6.final__first_scrapy-rekTiTXv__400173__tldextract-3.4.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [filelock] DEBUG: Attempting to release lock 140382385887728 on /home/user/.cache/python-tldextract/3.10.6.final__first_scrapy-rekTiTXv__400173__tldextract-3.4.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [filelock] DEBUG: Lock 140382385887728 released on /home/user/.cache/python-tldextract/3.10.6.final__first_scrapy-rekTiTXv__400173__tldextract-3.4.0/publicsuffix.org-tlds/de84b5ca2167d4c83e38fb162f2e8738.tldextract.json.lock
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (520) <GET https://book24.ru/product/transhumanism-inc-6015821/> (referer: None)
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <520 https://book24.ru/product/transhumanism-inc-6015821/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 243,
 'downloader/request_count': 1,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 7640,
 'downloader/response_count': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/520': 1,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.364996,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 20, 19, 10, 23, 800623),
 'httperror/response_ignored_count': 1,
 'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/520': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 8,
 'log_count/INFO': 11,
 'memusage/max': 65613824,
 'memusage/startup': 65613824,
 'response_received_count': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 20, 19, 10, 23, 435627)}
2023-01-20 22:10:23 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

**First** try - tried adding `headers` cause [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129054/scrapy-how-to-resolve-520) it's been written that some sites block robot requests and you should add headers to look like you're regular user with web browser. But it doesn't help and returns 520 error again.

```
import scrapy

class BookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'book24-2'
    start_urls = ['https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/']
    
    def parse(self, response):
        headers = {
        'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'
        }
        
        for link in response.css('div.product-card__image-holder a::attr(href)', headers=headers).get():
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_book, headers=headers)

        for i in range(1, 25):
            next_page = f'https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/page-{i}/'
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse, headers=headers)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        yield{
            'name': response.css('h1.product-detail-page__title::text').get(),
            'buy': response.css('p.product-detail-page__purchased-text::text').get().split()[1],
            'type': response.css('div.product-characteristic__value a::attr(title)')[2].get()
        }
```

**Second** try - tried changing `ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True` to `False` in settings.py - 520 error persists.

**Third** try - tried using `fake_useragent` lib - didn't help.
The code:

```
    import scrapy
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

# print(scrapy.Request('https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/'))

class BookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'book24-2'
    start_urls = ['https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/']
    
    # self значит, что остаемся в пределах этого класса
    # response это ответ, который видели в scrapy shell, к примеру, response.css('...')
    def parse(self, response):
        # headers = {
        # 'user-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'
        # }
        headers = {
        'user-agent' : UserAgent().random
        }
        
        for link in response.css('div.product-card__image-holder a::attr(href)', headers=headers).get():
            # yield - ключевое слово в scrapy, которое позволяет выполнять разные действия
            # yield scrapy.Request('https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/', headers=headers)
            # print('++++++++++++'+response)
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_book, headers=headers)

        for i in range(1, 25):
            next_page = f'https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/page-{i}/'
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse, headers=headers)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        headers = {
        'user-agent' : UserAgent().random
        }
        
        yield{
            'name': response.css('h1.product-detail-page__title::text', headers=headers).get(),
            'buy': response.css('p.product-detail-page__purchased-text::text', headers=headers).get().split()[1],
            'type': response.css('div.product-characteristic__value a::attr(title)', headers=headers)[2].get()
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your spider code that need to be addressed.

1. your css selector has a keyword argument headers which is preventing you from crawling the book pages.

```
for link in response.css('div.product-card__image-holder a::attr(href)', headers=headers).get():
```

2. From what I can tell there are only 14 pages of books and you have your for loop range set to 25.

```
for i in range(1, 25):
```

3. your `'type'` field in your item is addressing a specific index, however not all the book characteristics are uniform formatting so in over half of the book pages, the element you are trying to scrape doesn't exist.

```
'type': response.css('div.product-characteristic__value a::attr(title)')[2].get()
```

All of these are pretty easy fixes though.  For the `type` field you can simply iterate through the characteristic labels until you reach the one that you are looking for and extract the info and break iteration.

For example:

```
import scrapy

class BookSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'book24-2'
    start_urls = ['https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/']
    custom_settings = {
    "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY": False,
    "USER_AGENT": 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.css('div.product-card__image-holder a::attr(href)').getall():
            yield response.follow(link, callback=self.parse_book)

        for i in range(1, 14):
            next_page = f'https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/page-{i}/'
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        item = {
            'name': response.css('h1.product-detail-page__title::text').get(),
            'buy': response.css(
                'p.product-detail-page__purchased-text::text').get().split()[1]}
        for trait in response.css('div.product-characteristic__item'):
            label = trait.xpath('./dt/span/text()').get()
            if "Серия:" in label:   # <- change the label to the one you are looking for
                item["type"] = trait.xpath('./dd/a/@title').get()
                break
        yield item
```

running the above this was a portion of my output.

```
{'name': ' Гонки химер ', 'buy': '738', 'type': None}
2023-01-20 13:14:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://book24.ru/product/sobaka-baskerviley-5375698/>
{'name': ' Дойл Артур Конан: Собака Баскервилей ', 'buy': '1063', 'type': 'Классика на пятерочку!'}
2023-01-20 13:14:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://book24.ru/product/effektivnaya-biznes-kommunikatsiya-volshebnye-tabletki-dlya-delovykh-lyudey-5401347/> (referer: https://book24.ru/knigi-
bestsellery/)
2023-01-20 13:14:16 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://book24.ru/product/effektivnaya-biznes-kommunikatsiya-volshebnye-tabletki-dlya-delovykh-lyudey-5401347/>
{'name': ' Северская Ольга Игоревна, Селезнева Лариса Васильевна: Эффективная бизнес-коммуникация. "Волшебные таблетки" для деловых людей ', 'buy': '998', 'type': 'Тотальный диктант. Фонд поддержки языковой культу
ры граждан'}
2023-01-20 13:14:16 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://book24.ru/product/chto-budet-dalshe-iskusstvo-prevrashchat-istorii-v-stsenarii-5956711/> (referer: https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/)
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://book24.ru/product/chto-budet-dalshe-iskusstvo-prevrashchat-istorii-v-stsenarii-5956711/>
{'name': ' Что будет дальше? Искусство превращать истории в сценарии ', 'buy': '1095', 'type': 'Мастер сцены'}
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://book24.ru/product/predvestnik-zemletryaseniya-5449404/> (referer: https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/)
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://book24.ru/product/tolko-esli-ty-zakhochesh-5406995/> (referer: https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/)
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://book24.ru/product/opyty-bespriyutnogo-neba-5455029/> (referer: https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/)
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://book24.ru/product/predvestnik-zemletryaseniya-5449404/>
{'name': ' Джонс Сюзанна: Предвестник землетрясения ', 'buy': '1131', 'type': 'Кинопремьера мирового масштаба'}
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://book24.ru/product/tolko-esli-ty-zakhochesh-5406995/>
{'name': ' Комб Брюно: Только если ты захочешь ', 'buy': '771', 'type': 'Самый сильный наркотик — любовь'}
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://book24.ru/product/klub-samoubiyts-5409602/> (referer: https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/)
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://book24.ru/product/opyty-bespriyutnogo-neba-5455029/>
{'name': ' Гаврилов Степан Егорович: Опыты бесприютного неба ', 'buy': '667', 'type': 'Вперед и вверх. Современная проза'}
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://book24.ru/product/esli-by-eti-krylya-mogli-letat-5477816/> (referer: https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/)
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://book24.ru/product/klub-samoubiyts-5409602/>
{'name': ' Роберт Льюис Стивенсон: Клуб самоубийц ', 'buy': '3842', 'type': 'Эксклюзивная классика'}
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://book24.ru/product/rabota-nad-oshibkoy-5358564/> (referer: https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/)
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://book24.ru/product/esli-by-eti-krylya-mogli-letat-5477816/>
{'name': ' Если бы эти крылья могли летать ', 'buy': '1424', 'type': 'Young Adult. Важные книги для молодёжи'}
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://book24.ru/product/rabota-nad-oshibkoy-5358564/>
{'name': ' Петерсен Орсон: Работа над ошибкой ', 'buy': '967', 'type': 'Авангард. Современная интеллектуальная фантастика'}
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://book24.ru/product/upravlenie-vnimaniem-6660752/> (referer: https://book24.ru/knigi-bestsellery/)
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://book24.ru/product/upravlenie-vnimaniem-6660752/>
{'name': ' Король Александр: Управление вниманием ', 'buy': '675', 'type': 'Книги, улучшающие жизнь'}
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 175161,
 'downloader/request_count': 405,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 405,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 12608278,
 'downloader/response_count': 405,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 404,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'dupefilter/filtered': 199,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 56.672512,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 20, 21, 14, 17, 584866),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 52230852,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 404,
 'item_scraped_count': 390,   # <--- results
 'log_count/DEBUG': 801,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 404,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 405,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 405,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 405,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 405,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 20, 21, 13, 20, 912354)}
2023-01-20 13:14:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

As you can see the spider yielded 390 items.